Robotics Datasets
I am in the process of developing a ML model for improving robotic arm accuracy, but need help finding datasets that have things like sensor readings, control fusions, etc.
I am currently programming a neural network and want to integrate it to test with a simulated environment as well.
Does anyone have any recommendations for datasets and/or simulation environments?
